# Position a scaled-down background image at the bottom of the body region

Tags: xsl-fo, apache-fop

I need to display a large background image on the cover page. That image needs:

1. To be shrunk to the width of `region-body`.
2. To be positioned exactly at the bottom of `region-body`.

Using `background-image` is not an option since the image needs to be scaled. So I print the image in a long `region-before` that extends below the `region-body`. It works.

Then I try to position the image at the bottom of `region-before` using `absolute-position="absolute"` and `bottom="0cm"`. Unfortunately, `bottom` does not work the way I expected. (The image stays to the top.)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<fo:root xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format">
    <fo:layout-master-set>
        <fo:simple-page-master master-name="section1-cover" page-height="11in" page-width="8.5in"
            margin-top="1cm" margin-bottom="0">
            <fo:region-before region-name="xsl-region-before" extent="11in - 1cm  - .75in"
                background-color="beige"/>
            <fo:region-body margin-top="1cm" margin-bottom=".75in" margin-right=".395in"
                margin-left=".395in"/>
            <fo:region-after region-name="xsl-region-after" extent=".75in" background-color="orange"/>
        </fo:simple-page-master>
    </fo:layout-master-set>
    <fo:page-sequence master-reference="section1-cover">
        <fo:static-content flow-name="xsl-region-before">
            <fo:block-container margin-right=".395in" margin-left=".395in"
                absolute-position="absolute" bottom="0cm">
            <!-- I expected that block-container to go down to the bottom -->
                <fo:block line-height=".5">
                <!-- line-height="1" seems more logical but yields unwanted extra space -->
                    <fo:external-graphic src="url('cover-background.jpg')" width="100%"
                        content-width="scale-down-to-fit"/></fo:block>
            </fo:block-container>
        </fo:static-content>
        <fo:flow flow-name="xsl-region-body">
            <fo:block font-size="28pt">Title</fo:block>
        </fo:flow>
    </fo:page-sequence>
</fo:root>
```

Does anyone have a solution?

**Note**: I don’t want to position that image from the top, since I cannot reliably compute the image height after scaling.

**Note**: It has to work in FOP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `<fo:region-before display-align="after" />` (and omit the `fo:block-container`).  See https://www.w3.org/TR/xsl11/#display-align.

The FOP conformance page (https://xmlgraphics.apache.org/fop/compliance.html) states that FOP has partial conformance, so YMMV.

---

In the words of Larry Wall, there is more than one way to do it:

```
<fo:root xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format">
  <fo:layout-master-set>
    <fo:simple-page-master
        master-name="section1-cover"
        page-height="11in" page-width="8.5in">
      <fo:region-body
          margin-top="1cm"
          margin-bottom="0.75in"
          background-color="beige" />
      <fo:region-after
          region-name="xsl-region-after"
          extent=".75in"
          background-color="orange" />
    </fo:simple-page-master>
  </fo:layout-master-set>
  <fo:page-sequence master-reference="section1-cover">
    <fo:flow flow-name="xsl-region-body">
      <fo:block-container
          absolute-position="absolute"
          bottom="0in"
          left="0.395in"
          right="0.395in"
          display-align="after">
        <fo:block line-height="0">
          <fo:external-graphic
              src="url('cover-background.jpg')"
              width="100%"
              content-width="scale-down-to-fit"/>
        </fo:block>
      </fo:block-container>
      <fo:block
          margin-left="0.375in"
          margin-right="0.375in"
          font-size="28pt">Title</fo:block>
    </fo:flow>
  </fo:page-sequence>
</fo:root>
```

Tested with both AH Formatter V6.5 and FOP.

Comment: It works! (Well, kind of.) FOP requires that `<region-before>` come after `<region-body>` and that causes Antenna House (not FOP) formatter to display `<region-before>` over `<region-body>`. (A portable solution is welcomed.) Then I had to mess with `line-height` to get rid of what seems to be regrettable half-leading spaces. Setting it to `line-height=".5"` seems to work, don’t ask me why.

Comment: I thought that this only had to work on FOP.  If you wanted to indicate that it also needs to work with AH Formatter, you could have added the [antenna-house] tag.

Comment: AH Formatter allows `fo:region-*` in any order so you can render them in the order that you want.  `z-index` isn't allowed on `fo:region-*`, so that is a workaround.

Comment: If you were just using AH Formatter, you could use `text-depth="0"` to get rid of the half-leading (see https://www.w3.org/TR/xsl11/#text-depth).  The way that also works with FOP is to just use `line-height="0"` and rely on the default value of `line-stacking-strategy` being `max-height` (see https://www.w3.org/TR/xsl11/#line-stacking-strategy and https://www.w3.org/TR/xsl11/#area-line).

Comment: Thank you for your update (and for citing Larry Wall). I am adopting _your_ way to do it as the most understandable, with all the magic located in one `fo:block-container`.

Comment: Our sworn requirement is only to have it work with FOP, but there are obvious benefits (for me as for other readers) to portable solutions. To mention one, as I wrote to @Hobbes, being able to test my `fo` code in the Antenna House viewer saves me some time.

Comment: `font-size="0"` gives a better result than `line-height="0"`. The latter has the image exceed the bottom a bit.

Answer (score 0):

You can use background-image if you modify the image a bit. You can, for example create an empty background image of the same size as your page, and place your image in the correct position in this empty background.

And to find the image height after scaling:

1. Open the image in any image editor that supports working in real-world sizes (mm/in). Illustrator, Inkscape for example.
2. Scale the image to the width you want.
3. Measure the height (in Inkscape: by drawing a vertical line across the image).

Or to calculate it: 
you know the width (x) you want the image to have, and the native size of the image (height h and width w). The height (y) you want is (x/w)*h.

Comment: I would be very embarrassed to admit that FO is not able to adjust and align an image (while CSS is). That may put the whole project at risk. Plus, I am already struggling with multiple units (cm and in as you can see), multiple background images (for different audiences) and line-height jokes that defeat all measurement attempts with half-leading spaces.

Comment: If all attempts at calculation fail, I open the project in Antennahouse, use its rulers to measure where a block starts, then adjust my code to position the block where I want it.

Comment: You are right to mention the Antenna House viewer. It is a valuable tool that I recommend to any learner like me. (Despite the disproportionately aggressive watermark.) I also use the `-awt` option on FOP, although it lacks debugging functions such as ruler or display of computed measurements.

Comment: The idea behind buying a license, besides getting rid of the watermark, is that it helps pay for the ongoing development and support of the product.  AH Formatter is commercial software, but what you get for your money is that valuable GUI for Windows, comprehensive XSL 1.1 support, extensions for aspects that XSL 1.1 doesn't cover, frequent (typically every 45 days) updates, and, yes, the absence of a watermark.